# Sitecore Item not indexing in Coveo while doing smart publish

Tags: coveo

As of now getting issue while publishing the `Sitecore` item then it's not going to `Coveo` `index`.

I am doing smart publishing for item and publishing item individually.

Can anyone help us, is there `republish` required in place of `Smart publish` for index the item from `Sitecore` to `Coveo`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question and many things can go wrong when indexing from Sitecore, but I can still give you some direction on how to troubleshoot this.

Coveo for Sitecore includes two indices by default: Coveo_master_index and Coveo_web_index.

When you publish an item, it is published to the "web" index in Sitecore, which triggers events in Sitecore's indexing pipeline that Coveo for Sitecore listens to. Those events include item information, and Coveo built its own item conversion on top of Sitecore's native events.

Now, the specifics are different from Sitecore version to version (and Coveo for Sitecore version), so I would first suggest that you try accessing the Coveo Diagnostic Panel (accessible from Sitecore's settings menu, in the Coveo section).

If there is nothing wrong on the page, I would suggest doing a full rebuild of both `Coveo_master_index` and `Coveo_web_index` by using the `Coveo Command Center` panel (only in Coveo for Sitecore 5+). When the rebuild is finished, ensure that the items you expected are in your index.

Then, I would suggest having a look at your Configuration files. Maybe there is a `coveoInboundFilterPipeline` that filters on this type of item, or maybe the `Coveo_web_index` scope does not include the path you are trying to publish.

At this point, if you are still having issue, you best bet is to contact support with as much information as possible, such as a Coveo Diagnostic Package, Sitecore versions, Coveo for Sitecore versions, logs, anything that you think might be of help.